# How to reduce time spent in GC

Tags: .net, performance, garbage-collection

I'm creating a desktop application that has a compute-heavy operation that potentially runs for several seconds. Obviously there is a need to minimize the time of this operation. The operation is fairly easy to parallellize (individual subtasks), and each subtask takes around 50ms on a single thread. On multiple threads, each subtask takes 4-5 times as long because 40-50% time is spent in GC, effectively cancelling the speedup completely.

So I need to give the GC less work. My first thought was to try to find which type of object was being garbage collected the most, but I realized that although I often do memory profiling, I had never searched for a pattern like this. Usually a look at heap snapshots, or differences between heap snapshots, but these show objects that are alive, not the objects that were created and disposed between those snapshots. So that is my first question: what is the easiest way to find which types are created and garbage collected the most? I tried looking for method call counts to see if some constructor was called suspiciously often, but all objects created in millions were only small struct types. These should have no effect on GC even if boxed if I understand things correctly?

The algorithm creates hundreds of thousands of individual result point objects. These of course aren't supposed to be gc'd because they represent the output of the operation. But it leads me to my second question: is the time spent in GC mostly dependent on the total number of objects or mostly depending on the number of objects actually collected? Should I try to limit the number of result objects and instead use fewer but larger result objects?

Edit: I found the time spent in GC by using the VS 2010 concurrency visualizer. Also, in the parallel piece of code most sections of blocked threads were waiting for gc

Edit: I should clarify that the performance problem is because the execution is effectively serialized on the workstation GC. See for example the performance problem described in this post.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hshafi/archive/2010/06/17/case-study-parallelism-and-memory-usage-vs2010-tools-to-the-rescue.aspx

I can't do anything about the garbage collector blocking my threads (and I don't think I want the server GC for a desktop app, correct?). So in order to get a linear speedup for this operation, I need to reduce the number of times the GC is invoked. Most of the time wasted is actually wasted by other threads blocked waiting for one thread to do GC.

Comment: Might it be faster to have the heavy calculation part be written in C or C++ and referenced as unmanaged code that way the GC has no influence over it?

Comment: Can you share the information leading you to believe the time is spent in the GC?  And, have you tried `GC.Collect` before you start the operation? (Perhaps to free up the previous resultset?)

Comment: There's something very fishy about the diagnostic.  It doesn't make sense that threaded subtasks that performs the same computation as one single-threaded task produce *more* garbage.  Unless the code is broken.  Start thinking about the effect of the heap lock and you might get somewhere.

Comment: @HansPassant I was just thinking that it was the *rate* of garbage creation that was increased thus giving he GC more work. Don't know if that makes sense. What do you mean by the effect of the heap lock?

Comment: @HansPassant please see my last edit for a clarification, I believe my problem is really that the high frequency of GC runs makes my code effectively serial. The % spent in GC figure was from ANTS performance profiler, I don't know if it is a reliable figure.

Comment: Well, that's one lead.  The *same* amount of GC work is needed but in *less* time because you made it faster.  So sure, the percentage goes up.

Comment: If you need throughput over low latency(and it seems like you do) you might try server GC.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I'll try it, but I thought there was a reason there was a different workstation GC? The problem here is that this is basically a long non-interactive operation in an otherwise interactive application. If I wanted to use the server version only for this operation, would I need a new process? I'm going to try setting the latency mode of the GC to low latency for the duration of the operation and see what that does.

Comment: You should profile and find out what objects are collected the most. I think memory profilers should be able to do this. Also, your assumption that boxed structs don't affect GC is wrong. Are you boxing structs? If so, why?

Comment: @svick I don't know if I am using boxed structs. This is a fairly large codebase, so this question is about what tools I need to use to find where I am giving the GC too much work, and how to use these tools. I have VS2010 and the ANTS profilers. A memory profiler like e.g. ANTS memory profiler does not tell you which class you have allocated the most, nor where in the code those allocations are made.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, if your tasks as taking only 50ms to execute, the overhead of thread creation etc, is going to take more more time than your actual jobs, which is what it appears that you are seeing.  So you might not be able to get too far into it.

As for seeing what is out there, the best tools that I've used are ANTS Profiler (Memory and Performance).  From there you can see objects in memory, and differences between points in time as well as "number of executions" which should get you what you want.

Comment: Yup, thread creation takes measurable time, which many people overlook.  Using a thread pool is better, but there's still a cost

Comment: I use the TPL so pooling should be taken care of. Also in my experience 50ms is well enough work to be done as a chunk of work on a separate thread. I have used ANTS memory profiler, but I haven't found a way to see which objects were created but are no longer alive. I used ANTS performance profiler to find out which constructors where called often.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look at increasing the cache hits between your objects.

So rather than creating new struct points and then performing calculations in lists/enumerables,  Have you tried allocating a fixed array of points and then continuously reusing the points.  That way you allocate the objects only once, perform your calculations and then return.  You will benefit from hot cache and you will not suffer any GC if you are able to completely reuse the array.

Comment: By the way, make sure you address @Mitchel Sellers comments too, you might be able to use the threadpool rather than explict threads, but context switch overhead is real and will have an effect on your performance too.

Comment: The inner parts of the heavy lifting is still well over 10.000 LOC so I need to find out where to focus the optimizations, for example by re-using allocated objects instead of allocating in a loop, or by changing the data layout or using unsafe code. Thread creation overhead is not an issue.

Comment: well you can go down to pointers, but I recommend using something like Redgate profiler first, find the hottest points of your code and see what you can do about them.  Sometimes things are done in the code which are having a dramatic effect on code.  Worst I've seen is reallocating buffers continously, destroys performance in GC.

Comment: Exactly, I need to find where I'm making the GC work. And that is exactly what I'm asking: which tools and how. I have used VS2010 and Redgates profilers but I can't see where I'm creating objects. One issue here is that the "working set" of data quickly grows to say 200MB, and the actual results are often 50-100MB of data that can't be GC:d since it represents the output. I'm worried that I'm straining the GC by creating a million objects taking 100MB, that I know myself should never be GC:d (during the course of the operation at least).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but for those that stumble on it...

I had exactly the same problem and fixed it permanently by setting server-mode garbage collection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357(v=vs.110).aspx.

In `app.config` add:

```
  <runtime>
     <gcServer enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
```

That already speeded my code up by an order of magnitude, with no side-effects that I could find.

If you know exactly where you're generating a lot of GCs, I also found that LowLatency http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gclatencymode(v=vs.110).aspx brought my GCs down to a single generation-1 GC:

```
GC.Collect ' pre-emptively collect before time-critical region
Dim oldmode As GCLatencyMode = GCSettings.LatencyMode
RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions()

Try
    GCSettings.LatencyMode = GCLatencyMode.LowLatency

    ' Work that allocates tons of memory here

Finally
    GCSettings.LatencyMode = oldmode

End Try
```

(The PrepareConstrainedRegions hopefully ensures that the Finally block is always executed, but I'm not entirely sure this is correct).

Answer (score 0):

These result point objects. As in the standard struct Point?
Can't say from here, but have you tried pre-allocating the space for them. Most of your GC calls could be allocating memory to them, that's a lot of effort, doing them in larger blocks, or even in one go if the amount can be calculated should give you a boost.

Another option might be trundling in to unsafe code, given you can gain that permission on the workstation.
Don't know hoe you have your points layed out, but might be some future in just allocating a block of memory and then ripping through it with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Even allocating all the points in an array would probably help and wouldn't require unsafe mode.

Comment: A lot of the objects created inside the result data are coordinate points yes (not the standard struct, but a similar struct with 2 doubles). I didn't think creating a lot of temporary value types would be a problem for GC. As for unsafe/perf, we are doing most of the heavy numerical work in native code already. These are the bits of code that structure and analyze those results, and they would be too difficult to create and maintain if it wasn't done "object oriented". So for example I'd like to keep the analysis done on arrays of structs rather than stucts of arrays and so on if possible.

Comment: Every creation of a point object means a call to the gc to find enough contiguous memory for it, mark it up as allocated, etc.. If they are objects, each one will be checked each GC pass. If you can do it in blocks, it's bound to give the GC less to do. Worse still 2 doubles isn'ta  lot of memory so unless you are instancing them in a very tight loop, they could be all over the and your GC time is probably defragging...